# Chrome: manage extension settings always opens in non-incognito window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

### Summary

I'm working on a developer tool chrome extension, often this tool is used with multiple instances of chrome open, including incognito windows. This extension has configurations that can be managed in the extension settings page.

### Issue

The desired behavior is when a user opens the extension settings, it opens in the window in focus. When the focused window is incognito, the settings page is opened in any of the non-incognito instances, is there a way to force the extension to open on the focused windowed even it is an incognito window?

tech stack: svelte v1.0.0

### Code

`manifest.json`

```json
{
    "name": "cool-name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "good-description",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/icon_48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon_128.png"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage", "webNavigation", "http://target-webapp-url"],
    "options_ui": {
        "page": "options.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

`Popup.svelt`

```js
    <div id="header">
        <cx-heading size="medium-large">Heading-String</cx-heading>
        <button id="settingsBtn" on:click="{() => chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()}">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" fill="black" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="some-svg-string"></path>
                <path d="some-svg-string"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
```

### Things I've tried

- Tried adding `"incognito": "split",` to the manifest file, no change in behavior

Comment: Use ["incognito": "split"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestion, the docs made this move sound promising, unfortunately no change in behavior.

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome then. You can remove options_ui and instead add a button in poopup.html that will create the tab in the current window.